# NoClassDefFoundError on LocalFileSystemHolder when trying to import settings into Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

I am trying to import settings into Intellij from pycharm (that's worked in the past). I am getting the following:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:  Could not initialize class 
com.intellij.openapi.vfs.LocalFileSystem$LocalFileSystemHolder
```

[image]

Is this broken now?

Comment: Usually, NoClassDefFound exception means that the installation was corrupted for some reason. Try re-installing from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download . Your IDE settings will be preserved

Comment: If the problem remains, please contact JetBrains support team at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new for further assistance